# Неудачное завершение этапа установки "Выбор и установка программного обеспечения" при установке Debian 9

Tags: debian

Установку произвожу с флешки, где записан образ нет-инсталл. Все идет нормально до момента, когда выкачиваются все файлы и начинается процесс установки.

Перепробовал разные варианты форматирования дисков ноутбука, ставил Debian 8 - проблема остается.

Ранее (на другое железо) устанавливал Debian миллион раз, все было нормально.

В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увидеть бы лог ошибки. Так сразу и не скажешь, что там может быть. Вариантов много:

- Репозитории были изменены или более не актуальны, в связи с чем
  происходит ошибка.
- Несовместимость с оборудованием(железом ноута), из банального
  архитектура процессора. (стоит посмотреть данные образа и данные
  ноутбука)
- Битый образ(?), самый маловероятный вариант, но я думаю стоит скачать
  полный образ и опробовать с ним.
- Как вариант попробовать установить без ПО систему, и потом вручную,
  или же опять-таки из образа доставить нужное ПО.

Comment: Добавил логи. Похоже, не удается ему скачать какой-то пакет.

Comment: Скачивал вчера с оф сайта, не должен быть битый. Пробовал свой "боевой" архив Debian 8. Причина не в этом.

Comment: Исходя из логов, не может достучаться до репозитория с обновлениями гимпа и питона. Попробуй исключить гимп и питон из устанавливаемых пакетов, или указать более старую версию.
И, да. С какой локалью производишь установку? В бородатом 2006-2008 годах, была бага с не stable версиями, они выдавали тот же error code 1 с pkgsel. И это было на всех debian-based дистрах. Покури на этот счёт в интернете, может, проблема всплыла вновь. И ещё интересует момент с DPO or FUA. Есть данные ноутбука?

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, в корпоративной сети закрыто было скачивание некоторых файлов по маске. Разблокировали - все поехало.